# Deduce type based on existence of a trait

Tags: c++, type-traits, type-deduction

The following repo is attempting to take a std::tuple and iterate it to output various values associated with it.  The std::tuple is a vertex and the end use of this will be to call glEnableVertexArray and glVertexAttribPointer on the elements.

So far I've got iterating the tuple's component types working, as well as finding the offset within each tuple for each element.  However I get stuck with this function:

```
template<class T>
void EmitAttribute(T const & v, int stride, int offset, int i)
{
    std::cout << "Stride is " 
              << stride 
              << " element index " 
              << i 
              << " is at offset " 
              << offset 
              << " has 1 component " 
              << std::endl;
}
```

For basic types (non-structs), I want to emit " has 1 component".  For elements with a num_components trait I want to emit the number of components.  I tried:

```
template<class T, class S>
void EmitAttribute(T<S> const & v, int stride, int offset, int i)
{
    ...
              << " has " << T::num_components << " components " 
    ...     
}
```

But it doesn't compile.  How do I write the template such that one function is called when T doesn't have a num_components trait and the other is called when it does?

Full repo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<class T, int C>
struct vec
{
    typedef T value_type;

    enum { num_components = C };
};

template<class T>
struct vec2 : vec<T, 2>
{
public:

    T x, y;
    vec2(T X, T Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}
};

template<class T>
struct vec3 : vec<T, 3>
{
public:

    T x, y, z;
    vec3(T X, T Y, T Z) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z) {}
};

template<class T>
struct vec4 : vec<T, 4>
{
public:

    T x, y, z, w;
    vec4(T X, T Y, T Z, T W) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z), w(W) {}
};

namespace VertexAttributes
{
    template<class T>
    void EmitAttribute(T const & v, int stride, int offset, int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Stride is " 
                  << stride 
                  << " element index " 
                  << i 
                  << " is at offset " 
                  << offset 
                  << " has 1 component " 
                  << std::endl;
    }

    template<int index, class T>
    int ElementOffset(T & t)
    {
        return static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&std::get<index>(t)) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t));
    }

    template<int index, typename... Ts>
    struct Emitter {
        void EmitAttributes(std::tuple<Ts...>& t, unsigned size) {
            EmitAttribute(std::get<index>(t), size, ElementOffset<index>(t), index);
            Emitter <index - 1, Ts...> {}.EmitAttributes(t, size);
        }
    };

    template<typename... Ts>
    struct Emitter < 0, Ts... > {
        void EmitAttributes(std::tuple<Ts...>& t, unsigned size) {
            EmitAttribute(std::get<0>(t), size, ElementOffset<0>(t), 0);
        }
    };

    template<typename... Ts>
    void EmitAttributes(std::tuple<Ts...>& t) {
        auto const size = std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Ts...>>::value;
        Emitter < size - 1, Ts... > {}.EmitAttributes(t, sizeof(std::tuple<Ts...>));
    }
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::tuple<vec2<float>, vec3<double>, vec4<float>> vertexf;
    typedef std::tuple<vec2<double>, vec3<float>, vec4<double>> vertexd;
    typedef std::tuple<int, vec3<unsigned>, double> vertexr;

    vertexf vf = std::make_tuple(vec2<float>(10, 20), vec3<double>(30, 40, 50), vec4<float>(60, 70, 80, 90));
    vertexd vd = std::make_tuple(vec2<double>(10, 20), vec3<float>(30, 40, 50), vec4<double>(60, 70, 80, 90));
    vertexr vr = std::make_tuple(100, vec3<unsigned>(110, 120, 130), 140.5);

    VertexAttributes::EmitAttributes(vf);
    VertexAttributes::EmitAttributes(vd);
    VertexAttributes::EmitAttributes(vr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use just one class, and use `T data[N]` as data member, instead of `T data1, data2, data3, .... dataN`? Also, explore variadic template, and `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: I think you're suggesting I create a vec<T, 1>?  That would do it, yes.  With respect to how the data is stored for each element, I have choices.  I may use std::array or individual components or a union of the two.  It's just nice to sometimes write v[1] and sometimes to write v.y.

Comment: If you need good names as well, then you can have `x()`, `y()`, `z()` as member functions that `static_assert` the dimension to check the validity, and then use appropriate index to return the asked value.

Comment: OK there are various ways I can represent the actual components of the vector but that's not the question here as they're not referenced in the repo (I suppose I could have made a simpler repo).

Comment: You could use "Member Detector" C++ idiom: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a traits

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    decltype(T::num_components, void(), std::true_type{}) has_num_components_impl(int);

    template <typename T>
    std::false_type has_num_components_impl(...);
}

template <typename T>
using has_num_components = decltype(detail::has_num_components_impl<T>(0));
```

and then use SFINAE or tag dispatching:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!has_num_components<T>::value, std::size_t>
get_num_components() { return 1; }

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<has_num_components<T>::value, std::size_t>
get_num_components() { return T::num_components; }
```

And finally:

```
template<class T>
void EmitAttribute(T const & v, int stride, int offset, int i)
{
    std::cout << "Stride is "
              << stride
              << " element index "
              << i
              << " is at offset "
              << offset
              << " has "
              << get_num_components<T>()
              << " component "
              << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/XZO2mC)

Comment: out of interest, why does the decltype have the void() clause as its second argument?

Comment: @RichardHodges: To handle evil case with possible overloading coma operator of  `num_components`.

Comment: aha! Thank you. That's the great thing about c++, there's always something new to discover!

Comment: I think I'm butting my head up against some non-compliance (or the current state of C++ 11) in Visual Studio today, because your example gives me errors, i.e. "'VertexAttributes::has_num_components': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'".

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.  Visual Studio 2013 doesn't like the tag dispatching however.  I get the error regardless (with your demo too).  has_num_components returns the correct type (true or false), which is something.  Anyway I think I understand how it all works, so I suppose it's just a question of doing something else until MS catches up.

Comment: Ah that builds.  Nice one.  Thanks.